# How to add a serach bar for the <mat-select> component in angular 2

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-material2

This is my edited code please have a look and help me to implement the search and reset button.. please please

### Below shown is my .ts file.

```
import {Component, ViewChild} from '@angular/core';
import {MatPaginator, MatTableDataSource} from '@angular/material';
import { FormControl } from '@angular/forms';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/startWith';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

export class Dep {
  constructor(public name: string) { }
}



@Component({
  selector: 'app-account',
  templateUrl: './account.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./account.component.scss']
})

export class AccountComponent {

   dept = [
    'Administrative Computer',
    'Agosta Laboratory',
    'Allis Laboratory',
    'Bargaman Laboratory',
    'Bio-Imaging Resource Center',
    'Capital Projects',
    'Casanova Laboratory',
    'Darst Laboratory',
    'Darnell James Laboratory',
    'Deans Office',
    'Energy Consultant',
    'Electronic Shop',
    'Facilities Management',
    'Field Laboratory'
  ];
  deptControl: FormControl = new FormControl();
  filtereddept: Observable<string[]>;
  ngOnInit() {
      this.filtereddept = this.deptControl.valueChanges
          .startWith(null)
          .map(val => val ? this.filter(val) : this.dept.slice());
  }

  filter(val: string): string[] {
      return this.dept.filter(option =>
      option.toLowerCase().indexOf(val.toLowerCase()) === 0);
  }


  displayedColumns = ['accno', 'accdesc', 'investigator', 'accCPC','location','cdeptid','depdesc'];
  dataSource = new MatTableDataSource<Element>(ELEMENT_DATA);

  @ViewChild(MatPaginator) paginator: MatPaginator;

   ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator;
  }
}

export interface Element {
  accno: number;
  accdesc: string;
  investigator: string;
  accCPC: string;
  location:string;
  cdeptid: number;
  depdesc: string;
}

const ELEMENT_DATA: Element[] = [
  {accno: 5400343, accdesc: 'ASTRALIS LTD', investigator:'Kruger, James G.', accCPC: 'OR',location:'ON',cdeptid: 110350,depdesc: 'Kruger Laboratory'},

  {accno: 5400343, accdesc: 'ASTRALIS LTD', investigator:'Kruger, James G.', accCPC: 'OR',location:'ON',cdeptid: 110350,depdesc: 'Kruger Laboratory'},

  {accno: 5400343, accdesc: 'ASTRALIS LTD', investigator:'Kruger, James G.', accCPC: 'OR',location:'ON',cdeptid: 110350,depdesc: 'Kruger Laboratory'},

  {accno: 5400343, accdesc: 'ASTRALIS LTD', investigator:'Kruger, James G.', accCPC: 'OR',location:'ON',cdeptid: 110350,depdesc: 'Kruger Laboratory'},

  {accno: 5400343, accdesc: 'ASTRALIS LTD', investigator:'Kruger, James G.', accCPC: 'OR',location:'ON',cdeptid: 110350,depdesc: 'Kruger Laboratory'},

  {accno: 5400343, accdesc: 'ASTRALIS LTD', investigator:'Kruger, James G.', accCPC: 'OR',location:'ON',cdeptid: 110350,depdesc: 'Kruger Laboratory'},

  {accno: 5400343, accdesc: 'ASTRALIS LTD', investigator:'Kruger, James G.', accCPC: 'OR',location:'ON',cdeptid: 110350,depdesc: 'Kruger Laboratory'},

  {accno: 5400343, accdesc: 'ASTRALIS LTD', investigator:'Kruger, James G.', accCPC: 'OR',location:'ON',cdeptid: 110350,depdesc: 'Kruger Laboratory'},

  {accno: 5400343, accdesc: 'ASTRALIS LTD', investigator:'Kruger, James G.', accCPC: 'OR',location:'ON',cdeptid: 110350,depdesc: 'Kruger Laboratory'},

  {accno: 5400343, accdesc: 'ASTRALIS LTD', investigator:'Kruger, James G.', accCPC: 'OR',location:'ON',cdeptid: 110350,depdesc: 'Kruger Laboratory'},

  {accno: 5400343, accdesc: 'ASTRALIS LTD', investigator:'Kruger, James G.', accCPC: 'OR',location:'ON',cdeptid: 110350,depdesc: 'Kruger Laboratory'},

  {accno: 5400343, accdesc: 'ASTRALIS LTD', investigator:'Kruger, James G.', accCPC: 'OR',location:'ON',cdeptid: 110350,depdesc: 'Kruger Laboratory'},

  {accno: 5400343, accdesc: 'ASTRALIS LTD', investigator:'Kruger, James G.', accCPC: 'OR',location:'ON',cdeptid: 110350,depdesc: 'Kruger Laboratory'},

  {accno: 5400343, accdesc: 'ASTRALIS LTD', investigator:'Kruger, James G.', accCPC: 'OR',location:'ON',cdeptid: 110350,depdesc: 'Kruger Laboratory'},

  {accno: 5400343, accdesc: 'ASTRALIS LTD', investigator:'Kruger, James G.', accCPC: 'OR',location:'ON',cdeptid: 110350,depdesc: 'Kruger Laboratory'}

];
```

### Below shown is my .html file.

```
 <table>

<tr><td>Account Maintenance</td><td></td></tr>

<tr><td>Client Account ID</td>
<td>
  <mat-form-field>
    <input matInput placeholder="       ">
  </mat-form-field><br/>
</td>
</tr>

<tr><td>  Account Description</td>
<td>
  <mat-form-field>
    <input matInput placeholder="     ">
  </mat-form-field><br/>
</td>
</tr>

<tr><td> Investigator</td>
<td>
  <mat-form-field>
    <input matInput placeholder="   ">
  </mat-form-field><br/> 
</td>
</tr>

 <tr><td> Department</td>
<td>
  <mat-form-field>

           <input type="text" placeholder="Search.." matInput [formControl]="deptControl" [matAutocomplete]="auto">
        <mat-autocomplete #auto="matAutocomplete">
            <mat-option *ngFor="let dep of filtereddept | async" [value]="dep">
                {{ dep }}
            </mat-option>
        </mat-autocomplete>

</mat-form-field><br/>
</td>
</tr>


</table>

<br><br>

<button >Search</button>

<button >Reset</button>

<button >Close</button>


<mat-card>
<div class="example-container mat-elevation-z8">
  <mat-table #table [dataSource]="dataSource">

    <!-- Account No. Column -->
    <ng-container matColumnDef="accno">
      <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Account No. </mat-header-cell>
      <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.accno}} </mat-cell>
    </ng-container>

    <!-- Account Description Column -->
    <ng-container matColumnDef="accdesc">
      <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Account Description </mat-header-cell>
      <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.accdesc}} </mat-cell>
    </ng-container>

    <!-- Investigator Column -->
    <ng-container matColumnDef="investigator">
      <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Investigator </mat-header-cell>
      <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.investigator}} </mat-cell>
    </ng-container>

    <!-- Account CPC Column -->
    <ng-container matColumnDef="accCPC">
      <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Account CPC </mat-header-cell>
      <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.accCPC}} </mat-cell>
    </ng-container>

     <!-- Location Column -->
    <ng-container matColumnDef="location">
      <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Location </mat-header-cell>
      <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.location}} </mat-cell>
       </ng-container>


 <!-- Client Dept ID Column -->
    <ng-container matColumnDef="cdeptid">
      <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> ClientDeptID </mat-header-cell>
      <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.cdeptid}} </mat-cell>
       </ng-container>


        <!-- Dept Description Column -->
    <ng-container matColumnDef="depdesc">
      <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Dept Description  </mat-header-cell>
      <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.depdesc}} </mat-cell>
       </ng-container>


    <mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></mat-header-row>
    <mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></mat-row>
  </mat-table>

  <mat-paginator #paginator
                 [pageSize]="10"
                 [pageSizeOptions]="[5, 10, 20]">
  </mat-paginator>
</div>
</mat-card>
```

Here i want to display table as i press the search button and want to reset the values of the  form on pressing the reset button..

please help me in this ...

Comment: why dont you use mat-autocomplete?

Comment: hmm ok  i will try this out

Comment: thankyou very much ..its working ..

Comment: i implemented a reset button for this option to get reset when needed ,but my button is not working. can you please help me to reset its value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [**`mat-autocomplete`**](https://material.angular.io/components/autocomplete/overview). Change your template to this:

```
<form>
    <mat-form-field>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Search.." matInput [formControl]="deptControl" [matAutocomplete]="auto">
        <mat-autocomplete #auto="matAutocomplete">
            <mat-option *ngFor="let dep of filtereddept | async" [value]="dep">
                {{ dep }}
            </mat-option>
        </mat-autocomplete>
    </mat-form-field>
</form>
```

... and your typescript code to this:

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';
import { FormControl } from '@angular/forms';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/startWith';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-account',
  templateUrl: './account.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./account.component.scss']
})

export class AccountComponent {    
  dept = [
    'Administrative Computer',
    'Agosta Laboratory',
    'Allis Laboratory',
    'Bargaman Laboratory',
    'Bio-Imaging Resource Center',
    'Capital Projects',
    'Casanova Laboratory',
    'Darst Laboratory',
    'Darnell James Laboratory',
    'Deans Office',
    'Energy Consultant',
    'Electronic Shop',
    'Facilities Management',
    'Field Laboratory'
  ];
  deptControl: FormControl = new FormControl();
  filtereddept: Observable<string[]>;
  ngOnInit() {
      this.filtereddept = this.deptControl.valueChanges
          .startWith(null)
          .map(val => val ? this.filter(val) : this.dept.slice());
  }

  filter(val: string): string[] {
      return this.dept.filter(option =>
      option.toLowerCase().indexOf(val.toLowerCase()) === 0);
  }

}
```

Remember, you will need to add **`ReactiveFormsModule`** in your module. Link to working [**StackBlitz demo**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ng-mat-beta-12-h5aape?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts).

Comment: thnakyou so much .. please can you see my edited code and help me to implement the search and reset button

Comment: @Heena please fork the stackblitz demo and add your code there which is not working, then I can have a look.

Comment: ok .. i saved and this is the link https://stackblitz.com/edit/ng-mat-beta-12-zk5thx?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts

Comment: fix all the bugs first , unfortunately your code doesn't compile

Comment: hmm ..ok ... i will try